# Mailhog is not working in Laravel 8.x + Sail

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sail, mailhog

I'm using [Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail) with Laravel 8.x
I set it up and it's working perfectly.
However, as said here in the [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#previewing-emails), I'm supposed to be able to access the **MailHog** web interface at: http://localhost:8025 since I configured my **.env** like this:

```
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

But http://localhost:8025 shows me **This page isn’t working**

Any help? Please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This my docker-compose.yml file

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmeilisearch:/data.ms'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
       image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
       volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
       networks:
           - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
    sailmeilisearch:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Make sure to restart your sail service.

Answer (score 2):

This applies to Laravel 9.x + Sail as well.

Mailhog is not installed by default within the docker-compose file when using Sail, and there is no mention of enabling it within the official docs (which is one of many things wrong with the Laravel documentation, but...).

As hinted at by the accepted answer, you need to add the following to your docker-compose.yml file:

```
mailhog:
    image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
        - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
    networks:
        - sail
```

After restarting Sail, you can then access the Mailhog web interface at localhost:8025

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "localhost" try with "mailhog"
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to run this after adding Mailhog to docker-compose.yml

```
sail up
```